# How to execute or run shell command in std::thread or pthread?

Tags: c++, shell, pthreads, stdthread

One of the application processes on the FreeBSD based OS that I work on, is multi-threaded.
Since `system()` and `popen()` fork a new **process**, it would not be a good idea to invoke them from a thread dealing with critical sections and mutexes.

What are the other alternatives to run shell commands in std::thread or pthread?

Comment: This does not make much sense. Yeah, `system` does spawn a new process, but it has nothing to do with the thread it was spawned from. Perhaps you are looking for a way to run process asynchronously, without halting the caller?

Comment: "Perhaps you are looking for a way to run process asynchronously, without halting the caller"  Yes.

Comment: then you will need to call `fork` + `exec` and poke running process with `wait` periodically until it quits.

Comment: Will only using `fork` + `execl` + (`waitpid` in a while loop) suffice or I need to do something with signal etc.?

Comment: Typically messing with signals in unavoidable anyway. But it is not that you need to perform any special signal handling when spawning a child process. Usual block all signals in all threads + single special thread flagging arrival of SIGTERM should be sufficient.

Comment: That helps! Thanks. I will try and test that out.